# How i can get the connected user data in a form type class without recover all data for another user’s (city for example)

Tags: php, symfony

How i can get the connected user data in a form type class without recover all data for another user’s (city for example). I use the ManyToMany relation.
I wish to recover the city of the author here. And the totalities of cities available in the database.

My form

```
<?php
​
namespace App\Form;
​
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
​
class OneNewCarType extends AbstractType
{
    private $security;
​
    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }
​
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser()->getCity();
​
        $builder
            ->add(
                'city',
                EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => User::class,
                    'label' => 'Ville',
                    'choice_label' => function () {
                        return $this->security->getUser()->getCity();
                    },
                    'expanded' => true,
                    'attr' => [
                        'class' => 'selectpicker',
                    ],
                ]
            );
    }
​
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'oneNewCarType';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, these solutions worked.

```
$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => User::class,
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.id = :user_id')
            ->setParameter('user_id', $this->security->getUser()->getId());
    }
]);
```

Or in the controller directly

```
/**
     * @Route("/classified/new", name="classified_create")
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     * @param CreateVehicleFlow $createVehicleFlow
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create(Request $request, ObjectManager $manager, CreateVehicleFlow $createVehicleFlow)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $vehicle = new CarVehicle();
        $vehicle->setCity($user->getCity());
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do, but if you want the `choice_label`'s to be the city of the user they are selecting you need to make the following change:

```
'choice_label' => function ($user) {
    return $user()->getCity();
},
```

So for each user as value in your select options the label for that option will be the user's city.